# Buttons (toggle buttons?) instead of radio buttons in an ActiveRecord form using bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to have a selector for "priority" on my form that looks like this:
[image: Toggle Buttons]

But can't figure out how to link it up to activerecord.  This is the straight-HTML for the "toggle buttons":

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i> &nbsp; Low</a>
   <a class="btn btn-warning active" href="#"><!-- i class="icon-white icon-adjust"></i--> Medium</a>
   <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i> &nbsp; High</a>
</div>
```

And I've got it working with Radio buttons, so thinking maybe I can just style them to look like regular inline buttons.  Not sure if I can specify a class for each button without some JQuery:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :priority, [["C - Low", 'Low'],
                                           ["B - Medium", 'Medium'],
                                           ["A - High", 'High']], :first, :last %>
```

Any ideas on how to make it look like buttons with the active one pressed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a hidden input field that binded directly to the priority column in the database:

```
<%= f.input :priority, as: :hidden %>
```

Then using jquery to make the buttons clickable (and change the value in the hidden field).